# Average over rolling date period

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 4 dimensions, which one of them is date. I need to calculate for each date, the average in the last 30 days, per each dimension value.

I have tried to run average over a partition by the 4 dimensions in a form of:

```
SELECT
Date, Produce,Company, Song, Revenues,
Average(case when Date between Date -Interval '31' day and Date - Interval '1' Day then Revenues else null End) over (partition by Date,Company,Song,Revenues order by Date) as "Running Average"
From 
Base_Table
```

I get only nulls with every aggregation I tried.
Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT
Date, Produce,Company, Song, Revenues,
Average(Revenues) over (partition by Company,Song rows between 30 preceding and current row) as "Running Average"
From 
Base_Table
```

Comment: ... and remove the `date` from `partition by`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fa06 How do you know that the result refer to the last x days if there is no order by clause?

Comment: I would think you'd need to include `ORDER BY <DATE COLUMN> DESC`